# FInd relationships within three products

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using PHP and MySQL

If I have the following tables

```
items
----
|order_id|sku|
|------------|
|   1    | A |
|   1    | B |
|   1    | C |
|   1    | D |
|   1    | E | 
|   2    | B |
|   2    | C |
|   2    | D |
|   3    | D |
|   3    | E |
|   3    | F | 
|   4    | A | 
|   4    | B | 
|   4    | C |
|   4    | F |
--------------
```

I would like to retrieve the following info:

```
| original_SKU | bought_with_a | bought_with_a | times_bought_together |
|--------------|---------------|---------------|-----------------------|
|       A      |      B        |        C      |           2           |
|       B      |      A        |        C      |           2           |  
|       B      |      C        |        D      |           2           |
|       C      |      B        |        D      |           2           |
   ETC ETC
```

I am trying to count the number of times three products are bought together.
This is an extension from this question:
[finding products that customers bought together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578216/finding-products-that-customers-bought-together)

Comment: Are you looking for an SQL only solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should follow the same approach as in that solution to get all 3-way combinations:

```
SELECT i1.sku as sku1, i2.sku as sku2, i3.sku as sku3, count(*) as bought_together
FROM items i1 join
     items i2
     on i1.order_id = i2.order_id and i1.sku <> i2.sku join
     items i3
     on i1.order_id = i3.order_id and i3.sku not in (i1.sku, i2.sku)
GROUP BY i1.sku, i2.sku, i3.sku;
```

You should be able to readily figure out how to extend this to more products, by adding more joins.

Answer (score 1):

Extending yesterday's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18578284/319542) -

```
SELECT d.original_SKU, d.bought_with1, d.bought_with2, count(*) as times_bought_together
FROM (
  SELECT a.sku as original_SKU, b.sku as bought_with1, c.sku as bought_with2
  FROM items a
  INNER join items b
  INNER join items c
  ON a.order_id = b.order_id AND a.order_id = c.order_id AND b.order_id = c.order_id 
      AND a.sku != b.sku AND a.sku != c.sku AND b.sku != c.sku) d
GROUP BY d.original_SKU, d.bought_with1, d.d.bought_with2
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce0c1/4/0)

Comment: this works, but recommend @GordonLinoff's answer