# Counting which products have been bought together

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a DF like this:

```
ID Product
1  1
1  2
2  2
2  3
2  4
3  1
3  2
4  3
```

Now I need in R a possibility like here:

[finding products that customers bought together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578216/finding-products-that-customers-bought-together)

My output should look like this:

```
ProductX ProductY Times
1        2        2
2        3        1
3        4        1
```

Nice would be a matrix output lile this:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] 
[1,]    1    2    0    0    
[2,]    2    1    1    0    
[3,]    0    0    1    1    
[4,]    0    0    1    1
```

I have tried it with the reshape2 package but I don't know how to get this output form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an answer using data.table and non-equi self-join. **Edit:** added `allow.cartesian = TRUE` to allow it work with large datasets.

```
library(data.table)

dt[dt 
    , on = .(ID = ID, Product < Product)
    , .(ProductX = x.Product, ProductY = i.Product)
    , nomatch = 0L
    , allow.cartesian = TRUE
   ][, .N, by = .(ProductX, ProductY)]

   ProductX ProductY N
1:        1        2 2
2:        2        3 1
3:        2        4 1
4:        3        4 1
```

Dplyr equivalent:

```
library(dplyr)

inner_join(tib, tib, by = 'ID')%>%
  filter(Product.x < Product.y)%>%
  count(Product.x, Product.y)

  Product.x Product.y     n
      <dbl>     <dbl> <int>
1         1         2     2
2         2         3     1
3         2         4     1
4         3         4     1
```

And here's a base R version as well:

```
aggregate(ID ~ Product.x + Product.y
          , data = merge(df, df, by = 'ID')
          , subset = Product.x < Product.y
          , FUN = length)

# Need to change the names from ID to n
  Product.x Product.y ID
1         1         2  2
2         2         3  1
3         2         4  1
4         3         4  1
```

**Performance:**

```
Unit: milliseconds
             expr     min       lq      mean  median       uq      max neval
           dt_way  3.9149  4.29330  4.593209  4.6597  4.80210   6.2326   100
 dplyr_inner_join  1.8218  1.91510  2.058864  2.0572  2.16205   3.0157   100
      dplyr_tidyr 13.8107 14.15735 16.020262 14.3571 14.78975 127.9654   100
         base_agg  2.3393  2.51215  2.586652  2.5804  2.63865   3.4415   100

n_IDs <- 1E3
n_Sims <- 1E5
ID_big <- sample(1:n_IDs, n_Sims, replace = TRUE)
Product_big <- sample(1:n_Sims, n_Sims, replace = TRUE)

: seconds
             expr      min       lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
           dt_way 1.633111 1.904460  1.998192  1.986452  2.110937  2.308671    10 
 dplyr_inner_join 5.606322 6.361026  6.574015  6.606423  6.839273  7.198770    10
      dplyr_tidyr 8.385418 9.350730 10.127512 10.372830 10.675809 11.462403    10
```

**Data:**

```
ID <- c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4)
Product <- c(1,2,2,3,4,1,2,3)

dt <- data.table(ID, Product)
tib <- tibble(ID, Product)
df <- data.frame(ID, Product)
```

Answer (score 2):

A different `dplyr` and `tidyr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 expand(Product, Product) %>%
 filter(Product < Product1)  %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 count(Product, Product1)

  Product Product1     n
    <int>    <int> <int>
1       1        2     2
2       2        3     1
3       2        4     1
4       3        4     1
```

However, I'm not sure what is the expected output for IDs that bought the same pair of products together (if there could be such a scenario) on multiple occasions.

Comment: This works perfect for me. With my real DF it takes about 1 H but the result is nice. Thank you!

Comment: My inner_join method is very similar to this. I added performance in my response - inner_join is about 7 times faster on this small dataset and about 2 times faster on a dataset with 100,000 results. The data.table solution is about 5 times faster on the dataset with 100,000 results.

Comment: Hey Cole, thanks. The Inner JOIN Solution is fast and the DT solution is a bit faster again. Perfect :)

Comment: Note tmfmnk is right about multiple products per group. With the inner_join, you'd have to add ```unique(df)%>%inner_join(.,.)``` to have an equivalent answer to tmfmnk's.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option using `dplyr` and `tidyr`. We `group_by` `ID` and create `list` of combinations taking a pair of `Product` at a time. For `ID` which have one `Product` we remove the `NA` values and finally `count` the combinations of `Product`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(new_col = if (n() == 1) list(as.character(Product)) else 
                    list(combn(sort(Product), 2, paste0, collapse = ","))) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  separate(new_col, c("ProductX", "ProductY"), sep = ",", fill = "right") %>%
  na.omit %>%
  count(ProductX, ProductY)

# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  ProductX ProductY     n
#  <chr>    <chr>    <int>
#1 1        2            2
#2 2        3            1
#3 2        4            1
#4 3        4            1
```