# Find Products customer bought together but non repeating columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, duplicates

I am using SQL Server and I'm trying to find out the top 2 products that are being bought the most together

This is a product table

[image]

I want it to be displayed as shown below:

[image]

I have tried

```
SELECT TOP 2 Product_Id, bought_with_Product_Id, times_bought_together 
FROM PRODUCT
GROUP BY Product_Id, bought_with_Product_Id, times_bought_together
```

Have tried this as well

```
SELECT TOP 2 *
FROM Product
WHERE times_bought_together = (SELECT MAX(times_bought_together) FROM product)
AND Product_Id <> bought_with_Product_Id
```

it returns

[image]

How do I make it so that product_id and bought_with_product_Id rows do not overlap

Comment: I'm confused, so the table already contains one other product that the product was bought with, and the times bought together? I guess I'm confused about the table you're querying to begin with. Seems odd.

Comment: i created a view following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578216/finding-products-that-customers-bought-together

Comment: So in your table sample above, are we to assume the first two rows are basically duplicates? That is, products 1 and 2 had a total of 3 sales? Or rather, should they have a total of 6 sales?

Comment: Yes, products 1 and 2 had a total of 3 sales. not a total of 6 sales

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exclude the duplicate rows using a `NOT EXISTS` test e.g.

```
declare @Test table (id int, otherId int, times int);

insert into @Test (id, otherId, times)
values
(1,2,3),
(2,1,3),
(4,1,2),
(1,4,2),
(1,5,1),
(5,1,1);

select top 2 *
from @Test T1
where not exists (
    select 1
    from @Test T2
    where T1.id = T2.otherId
    and T1.otherId = T2.id
    -- Keep the duplicate with the lower id
    and T2.id < T1.id
);
```

Returns:

| id | otherId | times |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 | 2 |

Note: Providing the DDL+DML for your test data (as shown here) makes it much easier for people to answer your question.

Comment: Thank you so much!